# Discard inline reply draft Outlook 2013 VSTO/Redemption

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-redemption

Is there any way to do the equivalent of a MailItem.Close(olDiscard) on the ActiveInlineResponse ?

I posed a related question and was steered to redemption RDO to create messages in a sent state, but redemption appears to only patch Send, not Close, Delete and the other ones missing from the MS API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redemption currently does not expose that functionality, but it would be a good idea to expose it through the SafeInspector object. It already exposes the ActiveInlineResponseSend method, it would be possible to also add ActiveInlineResponsePopOut and ActiveInlineResponseDiscard.

Send me an email to Dmitry at dimastr dot com, and I'll see what can be done...

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Yes, Redemption implements the `SafeExplorer.ActiveInlineResponsePopOut` / `ActiveInlineResponseDiscard` methods as of version 5.8 (the current version is 5.27).